# Extremely slow with Solr indexing - at any time only one Thread is executing, all others are blocked

Tags: performance, indexing, solr, bulk

Solr 9.2.1, it appears at any time only one Thread is executing and all others are blocked, though started 20 threads to index. We have 50 million objects to index and it will take 1 year.

Any suggestions to improve?

******All threads except one are blocked as below

```
"qtp1155757579-16" #16 prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=1070.17ms elapsed=337.00s tid=0x00007f915acc4000 nid=0xc716e waiting on condition  [0x00007f840985a000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(java.base@11.0.17/Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00007f8e1249aa60> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock$FairSync)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.base@11.0.17/LockSupport.java:194)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(java.base@11.0.17/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:885)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireShared(java.base@11.0.17/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1009)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireShared(java.base@11.0.17/AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1324)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock$ReadLock.lock(java.base@11.0.17/ReentrantReadWriteLock.java:738)
    at org.apache.solr.update.VersionInfo.lockForUpdate(VersionInfo.java:127)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.versionAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:351)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.processAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:236)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:55)
    at com.ptc.solr.update.processor.PTCUpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(PTCUpdateRequestProcessor.java:194)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.JavabinLoader$1.update(JavabinLoader.java:123)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec$StreamingCodec.readOuterMostDocIterator(JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec.java:342)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec$StreamingCodec.readIterator(JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec.java:286)
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.JavaBinCodec.readObject(JavaBinCodec.java:338)
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.JavaBinCodec.readVal(JavaBinCodec.java:283)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec$StreamingCodec.readNamedList(JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec.java:236)
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.JavaBinCodec.readObject(JavaBinCodec.java:303)
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.JavaBinCodec.readVal(JavaBinCodec.java:283)
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.JavaBinCodec.unmarshal(JavaBinCodec.java:193)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec.unmarshal(JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec.java:126)
```

******The only executing thread

```
"qtp1155757579-25" #25 prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=3635.83ms elapsed=336.95s tid=0x00007f915acd3800 nid=0xc7178 runnable  [0x00007f8409611000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixNativeDispatcher.unlink0(java.base@11.0.17/Native Method)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixNativeDispatcher.unlink(java.base@11.0.17/UnixNativeDispatcher.java:156)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.implDelete(java.base@11.0.17/UnixFileSystemProvider.java:236)
    at sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.delete(java.base@11.0.17/AbstractFileSystemProvider.java:105)
    at java.nio.file.Files.delete(java.base@11.0.17/Files.java:1142)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory.privateDeleteFile(FSDirectory.java:344)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory.deleteFile(FSDirectory.java:309)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.NRTCachingDirectory.deleteFile(NRTCachingDirectory.java:128)
    - locked <0x00007f8e11678d10> (a org.apache.lucene.store.NRTCachingDirectory)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.LockValidatingDirectoryWrapper.deleteFile(LockValidatingDirectoryWrapper.java:37)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexFileDeleter.deleteFile(IndexFileDeleter.java:763)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexFileDeleter.deleteFiles(IndexFileDeleter.java:757)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexFileDeleter.decRef(IndexFileDeleter.java:655)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexFileDeleter.decRef(IndexFileDeleter.java:686)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.decRefDeleter(IndexWriter.java:5851)
    - locked <0x00007f8e1180b968> (a org.apache.solr.update.SolrIndexWriter)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.StandardDirectoryReader.lambda$doClose$1(StandardDirectoryReader.java:466)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.StandardDirectoryReader$$Lambda$910/0x00007f83f55bdc58.close(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.StandardDirectoryReader.doClose(StandardDirectoryReader.java:482)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexReader.decRef(IndexReader.java:265)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexReader.close(IndexReader.java:411)
    - locked <0x00007f90153053a0> (a org.apache.lucene.index.StandardDirectoryReader)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.getReader(IndexWriter.java:687)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.StandardDirectoryReader.doOpenFromWriter(StandardDirectoryReader.java:381)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.StandardDirectoryReader.doOpenIfChanged(StandardDirectoryReader.java:366)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader.openIfChanged(DirectoryReader.java:246)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.openNewSearcher(SolrCore.java:2329)
    at org.apache.solr.update.UpdateLog.openRealtimeSearcher(UpdateLog.java:745)
    - locked <0x00007f8e11df7a20> (a org.apache.solr.update.UpdateLog)
    at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.deleteByQuery(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:590)
    - locked <0x00007f8e0d55a1a8> (a java.lang.Object)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.RunUpdateProcessorFactory$RunUpdateProcessor.processDelete(RunUpdateProcessorFactory.java:86)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processDelete(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:59)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.doLocalDelete(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:276)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.doLocalDeleteByQuery(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:1011)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.versionDeleteByQuery(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:980)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.doDeleteByQuery(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:938)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.doDeleteByQuery(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:913)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.processDelete(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:830)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processDelete(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:59)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.JavabinLoader.delete(JavabinLoader.java:230)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.JavabinLoader.parseAndLoadDocs(JavabinLoader.java:140)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.JavabinLoader.load(JavabinLoader.java:74)
```

Expect the 20 threads working in parallel

Comment: Since the thread is writing to disk, there isn't really much you can do? The index can only be written by a single thread at a time, so the idea is generally to not commit before you actually have to, such as using `commitWithin` or something similar, where the changes are actually persisted. How are you indexing your content?

Comment: Now confirmed the root - before indexing request sends to Solr, a deletion request will be issued first where the deletion request will blocked all other requests.